# Is there support for new row creation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Given the following UPSERT like scenerio:

```
EntityType myEntity = null;
if(newItem)
{
   myEntity = new EntityType();
}
else
{
  myEntity = context.TableName.Where(item => item.PrimaryKey == key).Single();
}

if(newItem)//This check bugs me
{
  context.TableName.Add(myEntity);//conditionally add the item to the context
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

I have to determine if the item needs to be added to the context.  Does the entity framework offer any kind of `context.TableName.NewRow()` or the like to save the last conditional check?  This way I can do something like this instead....

```
EntityType myEntity = null;
if(newItem)
{
   myEntity = context.TableName.NewRow();
}
else
{
  myEntity = context.TableName.Where(item => item.PrimaryKey == key).Single();
}   

context.SaveChanges();
```

A generic extension method should do this simple task for me, just seems odd (if) this does not already exist in the framework.

Comment: Why not put the `Add` in the first conditional?

Answer (score 1):

Does something like this work for you?

```
EntityType myEntity = null;
if(newItem)
{
   context.TableName.Add(myEntity = new EntityType());
}
else
{
  myEntity = context.TableName.Where(item => item.PrimaryKey == key).Single();
}   

context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This is certainly the right idea.  I want to be sure this type of functionality does not already exist in the framework.

Answer (score 0):

As it appears this is not available in the EF, I created my own extension to do it:

```
    public static T NewRow<T>(this System.Data.Entity.DbSet<T> entity) where T : class, new()
    {
        T t = new T();
        entity.Add(t);
        return t;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard EF Feature might be useful here

```
 Context.Set<TPoco>().AddOrUpdate(poco);
```